# Zendesk migration from Web Widget (Classic) to messaging web widget sdk

Tags: php, implementation, zendesk-sdk

The website is using the new SDK for Zendesk and I need to update the code, but the documentation is not really helpful.
I'm opening the widget like this:

```
zE('webWidget', 'reset');
zE('webWidget', 'open');
```

This is obviously not correct anymore

In the console:

```
Method webWidget.reset does not exist.
```

A note from Zendesk: API methods associated with the Web Widget (Classic) are still being executed on this page. This website is now using the new Web SDK (messaging experience) which no longer supports these APIs. If you don't intend to use the Web Widget (Classic), we recommend that you remove this code from your website.  Whilst not recommended, leaving them won't cause any issues. '

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use the functions for the Web SDK outlined in their [docs](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/zendesk-web-widget-sdks/sdks/web/sdk_api_reference/) instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that
zE('messenger', 'open');
To no avail

Comment: Resolved
So, in fact, zE('messenger', 'open') does work and that's the solution to adopt.
However zE('messenger', 'reset') is not supported which is what tripped me up when testing.
I used zE('messenger',  'close') instead

Answer (score 5):

Resolved
So, in fact, `zE('messenger', 'open')` does work and that's the solution to adopt.
However `zE('messenger', 'reset')` is not supported which is what tripped me up when testing.
I used `zE('messenger', 'close')` instead.